# Woocommerce Product image link to external affiliate link

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, external, affiliate

is it possible, that all woocommerce product links (image, title and „add to cart“ button) link to the external affiliate link and not to the product detail page? The add to cart button works, but the image and title redirect wrong. I think, anything is to change in this code (/woocommerce/content-product.php):

```
<div <?php fl_woocommerce_version_check( '3.4.0' ) ? wc_product_class( $classes ) : post_class( $classes ); ?>>
<div class="col-inner">
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' ); ?>
<div class="product-small box <?php echo flatsome_product_box_class(); ?>">
    <div class="box-image">
        <div class="<?php echo flatsome_product_box_image_class(); ?>">
            <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php
                    /**
                     *
                     * @hooked woocommerce_get_alt_product_thumbnail - 11
                     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
                     */
                    do_action( 'flatsome_woocommerce_shop_loop_images' );
                ?>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy `content-product.php` in your theme's `woocommerce` folder and then change `get_the_permalink()` with your affiliate link